# Why the thread does not stops?

Tags: python, multithreading

The thread started in the `start_thread` method does not stop. Why ?

```
import time
import threading

cont_running = True

def start_thread():
    threading.Thread(target=run).start()

def stop_thread():
    cont_running = False

def run():
    while cont_running:
        print 'Thread running : ' + str(cont_running)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    print 'Thread ended'

start_thread()
time.sleep(2)
stop_thread()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `stop_thread()`, your assignment statement creates a local variable named `cont_running`. This local variable is unrelated to the global variable of the same name.

Try this:

```
def stop_thread():
    global cont_running
    cont_running = False
```